# Android Room Database - LiveData - Update/Insert/Delete, skip observer (callback)

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, android-database

I'm new in Room Database, and recently I faced a problem that has to do with modifying the App's database (update/insert/delete) without causing the callback in observer to be fired.

This is the `Dao` class for my model:

```
@Dao
interface ReceiptRowDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM my_model ")
    fun getMyModels(): LiveData<MutableList<MyModel>>

    @Update
    fun update(receiptRow: ReceiptRow): Int
}
```

My `Database` class:

```
@Database(
        entities = [
            (MyModel::class)
        ],
        version = 1,
        exportSchema = false
)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun myModelDao(): MyModelDao
}
```

Usage:

```
class MyClass {
    val db: AppDatabase = Room
                    .databaseBuilder(mContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "my_db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()

    fun test() {
        val myLiveData = db.myModelDao.getMyModels()
        myLiveData!!.observe(this, Observer { data ->
                ...
                val item = data.get(0)
                item.id = 4
                // This update should not cause a callback
                db.myModelDao().update(item)
                ...
            })
    }
}
```

In the `MyClass`, the update instruction will cause an **infinite loop**, since an update to MyModel, will fire the observer. Then the code inside the observer will run again. This will do another update. This will fire the observer again and so on...

In such a scenario, is there a way to do the update of a model, but to skip the observers that might be listening for changes?

Comment: I have implemented this in java file. is it okay if i share java code?

Comment: @Raza sure, you're welcome.

Comment: why `update` at that point? The way the code is written in your example guarantees that the update does not change a thing about the item. You need to make that call conditional, only `update` when an update is needed, in which case a the second time the updated version hits your observer, it should not call `update` again.

Comment: @zapl It's supposed that some property is modified before update. I thought it was obvious but I'm going to edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: @DionisBeqiraj Just wanted to confirm if you are using two different Entities here, since, getMyModels is MyModel AND update is ReceiptRow ? Then how will they fix in loop? Have you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you could do is just simply check whether `data` is already in the database. Like

```
 fun test() {
    val myLiveData = db.myModelDao.getMyModels()
    myLiveData!!.observe(this, Observer { data ->
            ...
            val item = data.get(0);
            // This update should not cause a callback
            if (!db.myModelDao().itemExists(item){
            db.myModelDao().update(item)
            }
            ...
        })
}
```

Comment: Since this is about an update, it means that the `update` operation might be performed even on existing elements. And in that case, I don't want the observer to get fired.

Comment: @DionisBeqiraj can you then check whether the data is already updated? Anyway... it's a short-circuit solution. Can you use `SingleLiveEvent` and observe this instead of `myLiveData` ?

Answer (score 0):

this is the database class which holds the DAO classes along with its instance

```
@Database(entities = {Weight.class, DailyConsumption.class, DrinkType.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class MyDataBase extends RoomDatabase {

// DAO classes
public abstract WeightDao weightDao();
public abstract DailyConsumptionDao dailyConsumptionDao();
public abstract DrinkTypeDao drinkTypeDao();

private static MyDataBase dataBase;

public static MyDataBase getInstance(Context context){
    if (null== dataBase){
        dataBase= buildDatabaseInstance(context);
    }
    return dataBase;
}

private static MyDataBase buildDatabaseInstance(Context context) {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
            MyDataBase.class,
            Constants.DB_NAME)
            .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
}
}
```

and the part where you want to insert the data in database takes two parameters. one database class object and the entities. I have designed the entities classes like a model class which you can use to set and get values inside main class.

```
 dailyConsumption = new DailyConsumption();  // entity class
 myDataBase = MyDataBase.getInstance(this);
    dailyConsumption.setIcon(mIcon);
    dailyConsumption.setQuantity(mQuantity);
    dailyConsumption.setTime(strTime);
    dailyConsumption.setIsSelected(0);
    dailyConsumption.setDrinkUnit(drinkUnit);
    dailyConsumption.setDateTime(insertionDate);
    dailyConsumption.setDate(date);
    setDailyDataBase(myDataBase, dailyConsumption);
```

and the method setDailyDatabase just calls the database class to insert the entity

```
  private void setDailyDataBase(MyDataBase dataBase, DailyConsumption dailyConsumption) {

   // query takes parameters to update respective  columns
    myDataBase.dailyConsumptionDao().updateItem(mId, mQuanity, mTime, date);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers to my question. I need to perform an `update` inside an Observer which is listening for changes in the same model where the update occurs. I don't see any Observer in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, i would suggest you following way for observing `LiveData` & updation of your `Model`:

```
class MyClass {
val db: AppDatabase = Room
                .databaseBuilder(mContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "my_db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()

fun getDataObserver() = db.myModelDao.getMyModels()

fun test(item: MyModel) {
    db.myModelDao().update(item)
}
}
```

This will help you seperate your *observer logic* from *update logic*, now call `getDataObserver()` method where you want to observe data and use your test() method when you want to update your Model.